# How get only content of div with xpath?

Tags: php, parsing, xpath

I need to parse many pages and get content only on div with "description" class.

```
$curl = curl_init('http://optnow.ru/products/nabor:-setevoj-i-avtomobilnyj-adapter-pitaniya-dlya-noutbukov-deppa-slim-universalnyj-90-vt-d-21104-12-konnektorov-chernyj');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
$catalogHtml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$domCatalog = new DomDocument();
@$domCatalog->loadHTML( $catalogHtml );
$catalogData = new DomXPath( $domCatalog );
$xpathCatalogResult = $catalogData->query("//div[@class='tab-content description']//div//text()");
print_r($xpathCatalogResult);
```

But if I use it I get only

```
DOMNodeList Object
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    [length] => 1
)
```

How can I get the content of this?

Comment: Do you want to get HTML code of div found ?

Comment: @splash58, thanks man, I found solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I get it.

Solution:

```
    foreach ($xpathCatalogResult as $key) {
        print_r($key->nodeValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath expression can return scalar values. But only `DOMXpath:evaluate()` supports that.

```
var_dump( 
  $catalogData->evaluate("string(//div[@class='tab-content description']//div)")
);
```